# The column generation technique on a Train Unit Assignment Problem [Linear Programming]

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I am doing an assignment where I need to implement a mathematical model that I can't wrap my head around. For the technique of column generation, one would need to my understanding, a master problem and a subproblem to iterate over. I don't understand what the subproblem is in the (part of the) article below.

**Quick introduction:** The assignment of locomotives or train units to trips with a published timetable is a key problem to be faced by railway companies. Given a set of timetabled trips to be performed and a set of Train Units of different types, the TU Assignment Problem calls for the specification of the TUs to be used, and, for each of these TUs, of the associated trips.

Following is a part of the article I am working from:

**Problem description:**
Each trip is characterised by an arrival time and station and a departure time and station  and by a subset of TUs that can perform it. The sequencing constraints are represented by a directed acrylic multigraph $G(V, A)$ where nodes correspond to trips and in addition there are a dummy start node 0 and a dummy end node  0 + 1. An arc set $A$ is partitioned into $p$ subsets $A^k...,A^p$, where , is associated with TU types of type $k$ for $k$ $\in$ $1,.., p$. The dummy nodes are connected with all other nodes. The problem calls for the determination for each TU type $k$ $\in$ {1...p} of up to $d^k$ paths from 0 to n + 1 formed by arcs $A^k$, each path having cost $c^k$ and capacity $s^k$, such that each trip $j$ $\in$ {1,...,n} is visited by at most $u_j$ paths whose overall capacity is $r_j$, with the objective of minimizing the overall cost of the paths.

**ILP formulation:** For each $k = 1,...,p$ let $P^k$ denote the collection of all distinct paths rom 0 to n + 1 in $(V, A^k)$, and introduce an integer variable $x_p$ for each $P$ $\epsilon$ $P^k$, that indicates the number of times path P is selected in the solution. The ILP model is the following: 
$$ min \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{P\in P^k}c^kx_p, $$
$$ \sum_{P \in P^k} x_p\leq d^k, k = 1,...,p$$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{P\in P^k_j} s^kx_p \geq r_j, j =1,...,p$$
$$ \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{P\in P^k} x_p \leq u_j, j = 1,...,n$$
$$ x_p \leq 0, integer$$

This model has an exponential number of variables an thus is faster to solve by column generation techniques. Letting $J_P \subseteq {1,...,n} $ ne tje set of trips by a path $P \in P^k$ (k = 1,...,p), the dual of the LP relaxation of the model above reads:
$$ max - \sum_{k=1}^{p}d^k \alpha^k + \sum_{j=1}^{n} r_j \beta_j - \sum_{j=1}^{n}u_j \gamma_j,$$ 
subject to: $$  -\alpha^k + \sum_{j \in J_P} s^k \beta_j - \sum_{j \in J_P} \gamma_j \leq c^k, k = 1,...,p, P \in P^k,$$ 
$$ \alpha^k, \beta_j, \gamma_j \geq 0 $$

*Hence, the column generation problem, which is the separation problem for the above constraint, given a dual solution $\bar{\alpha}, \bar{\beta}, \bar{\gamma} $calls for k $ \in$ {1,...,p} and $ P \in P^k $ such that

$$ \sum_{j \in J_p}(s^k \bar{\beta_j} - \bar{\gamma_j} > c^k + \bar{\alpha^k}, $$
and can be solve as a maximum-profit path from 0 to n + 1 in $(V,A^k)$ with node profits $s^k \bar{\beta_j} - \bar{\gamma_j} $ for each $j \in$ V \ {0,n+1} by a canonical dynamic-programming procedure.*

My question relates to the cursive part. I understand that column generation is a procedure that starts with a small subset of the original (master) problem and then iterates over the sub problem looking for non-basic columns to add to the master problem until it fails to do so. What I don't understand is what is meant here by the separation problem, and what the sub problem is that I need to implement this model.

Thank you for your time!

Source: Cacchiani, V., Caprara, A., Toth, P. "Solving a real-world train-unit assignment problem". Mathematical Programming 2010.